# How to Create CSS Selector Element including index

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am building a selenium-based test application uses CSS Selectors or XPath strings, and am attempting to test menu items that appear on hover. Using "Inspect Element" in Chrome and in FireFox by right clicking, can verify that the right html is being highlighted, but when I copy the CSS Selector or the XPath, it sometimes selects multiple elements. For instance:

```
"#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a"
```

was what Chrome gave me, but it represents 13 elements in the DOM (each in a different sub-menu). The selector I need is the ninth element of the selector's result:

```
$("#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a")[9]
```

My main question is whether this can be represented as a CSS selector? I searched for an example but didn't find this particular problem.

```
$("#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a(9)")
```

Does not work - returns empty array.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you post some html

Comment: @Huangism - Yes, but the page is an internal one, and the DOM is pretty huge and non-specific. I am not really sure if the id is unique or not to be honest. I believe that BoltClock's answer is what I needed and am checking it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS does not provide a selector for the nth element matching some complex selector. jQuery makes up for this with the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector):

```
$("#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a:eq(8)")
```

Note that `:eq()` is 0-indexed, unlike `:nth-child()` which is 1-indexed, so this will return the ninth element that matches the selector `#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a`.

The equivalent XPath, should you choose to use that instead, is:

```
(id('myId')/li[2]/a)[9]
```

---

Your situation is unique, however, because if we assume that `#myId` is unique, as it should be, then you can use the CSS pseudo-class `:nth-of-type()` to find the ninth `a` child of the second `li` child of the element `#myId`:

```
$("#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-of-type(9)")
```

Note that `:nth-of-type()` and `:eq()` are not the same. `:nth-of-type()` behaves much like `:nth-child()` in that it considers children of the same parent, except that it looks at the element type, or the tag name. In this case, the element type we're concerned with is `a`.

The use of `>` combinators in your existing selector implies a parent-child relationship between your `li` and `a` elements, which is compatible with the `:nth-of-type()` selector. This is why I believe it can be used in your specific situation.

Comment: Wouldn't `#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(9)` work? Or can you not double up the nth-child?

Comment: @Huangism: No, that's different - `a:nth-child(9)` means the ninth child, which means each `li` must have at least 9 children, and the 9th child is an `a`.

Comment: Oh I see now, I miss read the question and did not realize the `:eq` applies to the result instead of the anchor alone

Comment: @Huangism: I just looked at the selector again, and there's also the fact that `>` combinators are used. Assuming the ID is unique, `#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(9)` couldn't possibly match up to 13 DOM elements. But I think there's a different way around this that could be possible with CSS.

Comment: OP mentions `"#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a"` matched 13 elements. I don't really know what to think now because I think the questions is not precise enough for me to understand. If we had the html and the OP mentions exactly what's needed, this would be easier

Comment: @Huangism: It just means `$("#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a").length` is 13. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/k4NfM

Comment: Yea I got that part I didn't get what you mean by the part where you mention can't match 13 DOM elements as I was just trying to match 1 element. Anyway, the css selector works as well http://jsfiddle.net/k4NfM/1/ or is this a bad example. O yea nvm, I guess if the li contained other elements it would not work and would have to use type

Comment: @Huangism: Bad example, I should have added some spans to show you where `:nth-child()` fails: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/k4NfM/2

Comment: It worked great as a selector! Thanks for the insight. However, I did find that I used $("#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a:eq(9)") get to the correct element. I think this is due to the fact that my other index is also outside of the css selector. ( $("#myId > li:nth-child(2) > a")[9] ) Thanks again!

Comment: One final note - while this works for a jquery selector, it does not work in a selenium JavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(javaScriptString) call. This is peripheral to this question, but does cause a bit of a pickle for executing a click right from this script. But I am thankful to know this method.

Comment: @Robb Sadler: In a zero-indexed system [9] really means the tenth element. You were probably looking for that, and not the ninth :) Glad I could help.